# Getting `Area code is already set` when running consumers

Tags: magento2, consumers

When I am running any of the consumers command from the console:

```
bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor
```

I am getting the following exception from the `vendor/magento/framework/App/State.php`, method: `setAreaCode($code)`: `Area code is already set`.

My current magento version is: **2.3.4**. Do you have any ideas why am i getting that exception ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a custom piece of code trying to set again the area code, while it is already set at a higher level. Search for usages of the `setAreaCode()` and see if you can isolate the culprit one.

Check this link, maybe it helps you https://support.klevu.com/knowledgebase/resolving-area-code-already-set/

Comment: Thanks @Diana, Indeed I have a module ,where someone did some changes with that method .. :(

Comment: For anyone who's struggling to locate the culprit, in the file "vendor/magento/framework/App/State.php", within the `setAreaCode` method, add the following in the first line: `if ( ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?? '') == 'bin/magento' ) file_put_contents( BP . '/var/log/setAreaCode.log', print_r(debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS, 10), true), FILE_APPEND );`. Once done, run the command again, and check the log in "var/log/setAreaCode.log". To fix the issue, refer to the link Diana has added in their answer.